# How to show multiple query results together with column name?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, group-by, union-all

I have four queries with data taken from same table.

```
select sum(unit_sold) as total_unit_sold 
from tewt 
where order_priority = 'HH'

union all

select avg(unit_sold) as average_unit_sold 
from tewt 
where order_priority = 'H'

union all

select max(unit_sold) as maximum_unit_sold 
from tewt 
where order_priority = 'M'

union all

select min(unit_sold) as minimum_unit_sold 
from tewt 
where order_priority = 'L';
```

I have used 'Union All' to depict all results without row and column names.

Result:

```
total_unit_sold (numeric)
1. 2401
2. 5362.00
3. 7699
4. 6184
```

But I don't know how to show them together with column/row name for each result.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: A mock up of the output you want would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in 1 query if you use `CASE` expressions for the 4 cases:

```
SELECT order_priority, 
       CASE order_priority
         WHEN 'HH' THEN 'total_unit_sold' 
         WHEN 'H' THEN 'average_unit_sold'
         WHEN 'M' THEN 'maximum_unit_sold'
         WHEN 'L' THEN 'minimum_unit_sold'
       END description, 
       CASE order_priority
         WHEN 'HH' THEN SUM(unit_sold) 
         WHEN 'H' THEN AVG(unit_sold) 
         WHEN 'M' THEN MAX(unit_sold) 
         WHEN 'L' THEN MIN(unit_sold) 
       END amount
FROM tewt 
WHERE order_priority IN ('HH', 'H', 'M', 'L')
GROUP BY order_priority
```

If you want all the values as 4 columns in 1 row you can do it with conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN order_priority = 'HH' THEN unit_sold END) total_unit_sold,
       AVG(CASE WHEN order_priority = 'H' THEN unit_sold END) average_unit_sold,
       MAX(CASE WHEN order_priority = 'M' THEN unit_sold END) maximum_unit_sold,
       MIN(CASE WHEN order_priority = 'L' THEN unit_sold END) minimum_unit_sold       
FROM tewt 
WHERE order_priority IN ('HH', 'H', 'M', 'L');
```

Or:

```
SELECT SUM(unit_sold) FILTER (WHERE order_priority = 'HH') total_unit_sold,
       AVG(unit_sold) FILTER (WHERE order_priority = 'H') average_unit_sold,
       MAX(unit_sold) FILTER (WHERE order_priority = 'M') maximum_unit_sold,
       MIN(unit_sold) FILTER (WHERE order_priority = 'L') minimum_unit_sold       
FROM tewt 
WHERE order_priority IN ('HH', 'H', 'M', 'L');
```

If `'HH'`, `'H'`, `'M'` and `'L'` are the only possible values of `order_priority` you can remove the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: the last two queries gives the desired result, thanks

Comment: the first one is pretty unique and nice to know, thanks

Comment: oo, i see, i can't accept two people's answers lol.... i am new here

Answer (score 2):

Have each select as a column expression instead of `UNION ALL`ing them together; this allows you to assign a column name to each sub-select.

```
SELECT
    (select sum(unit_sold) from tewt where order_priority='HH') as total_unit_sold,
    (select avg(unit_sold) from tewt where order_priority='H') as average_unit_sold,
    (select max(unit_sold) from tewt where order_priority='M') as maximum_unit_sold,
    (select min(unit_sold) from tewt where order_priority='L') as minimum_unit_sold;
```

It's unclear what you mean by 'row name' - you have 4 values, so it's either 4 rows x 1 column, like what you already have, or 1 row x 4 columns, as shown above.  If what you wanted was a 4x4, with rows labelled 'HH', 'H', 'M, 'L', columns labelled as in the existing query, and NULLS for the new cells, that's also possible, but more involved & I'm gonna let you clarify if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres, you would use conditional aggregation, which uses the `filter` clause:

```
select sum(unit_sold) filter (where order_priority = 'HH') as hh_total_unit_sold,
       sum(unit_sold) filter (where order_priority = 'H') as h_total_unit_sold,
       sum(unit_sold) filter (where order_priority = 'M') as m_total_unit_sold,
       sum(unit_sold) filter (where order_priority = 'L') as l_total_unit_sold       
from tewt ;
```

Comment: nope, this is not giving the correct result

Comment: Your comment is not helpful.  How is this not the result that you want?  It should be exactly the same logic as in your question, except the values in rows are in columns.